# java string concatenation and interning

Tags: java, string-concatenation, string-interning

Question 1

```
String a1 = "I Love" + " Java";
String a2 = "I Love " + "Java";
System.out.println( a1 == a2 ); // true

String b1 = "I Love";
b1 += " Java";
String b2 = "I Love ";
b2 += "Java";
System.out.println( b1 == b2 ); // false
```

In the first case, I understand that it is a concatenation of two string literals, so the result "I Love Java" will be interned, giving the result true. However, I'm not sure about the second case.

Question 2

```
String a1 = "I Love" + " Java"; // line 1
String a2 = "I Love " + "Java"; // line 2

String b1 = "I Love";
b1 += " Java";
String b2 = "I Love ";
b2 += "Java";
String b3 = b1.intern();
System.out.println( b1 == b3 ); // false
```

The above returns false, but if I comment out lines 1 and 2, it returns true. Why is that?

Comment: We never really compare strings using the == operator and use the .equals method instead

Comment: @JoeyPinto OP uses `==` to learn about Java internals, discovering behavior that looks pretty odd, yet has a reasonable explanation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first part of your question is simple: Java compiler treats concatenation of multiple string literals as a single string literal, i.e.

```
"I Love" + " Java"
```

and

```
"I Love Java"
```

are two identical string literals, which get properly interned.

The same interning behavior does *not* apply to `+=` operation on strings, so `b1` and `b2` are actually constructed at run-time.

The second part is trickier. Recall that `b1.intern()` may return `b1` or some other `String` object that is equal to it. When you keep `a1` and `a2`, you get `a1` back from the call to `b1.intern()`. When you comment out `a1` and `a2`, there is no existing copy to be returned, so `b1.intern()` gives you back `b1` itself.

Answer (score 3):

From intern() docs

> All literal strings and string-valued constant expressions are interned. String literals are defined in section 3.10.5 of the The Java™ Language Specification.

And from [JLS 3.10.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5)

> - Strings computed by constant expressions (§15.28) are computed at
>     compile time and then treated as if they were literals.
>
>   - Strings computed by concatenation at run time are newly created and
>       therefore distinct.

Your string b1 not actually interned. Hence the difference.