# StringBuilder creation using a loop best practice

Tags: java, stringbuilder

i wonder if this code that using StringBuilder is best efficient

or it still creating alot of temporry strings by concatenating the " " with current item?

if so can you suggest for better code?

```
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    for (long item : someListOfNumbers) {
        out.append( " " + item);
    }
    return out.toString();
}
```

Comment: Like `out.append(' ').append(item);`?

Comment: That will cause a leading whitespace, I don't know if it is desired or not.

Answer (score 4):

For this particular use case you probably want to use [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html), unless your goal is to have a leading space in the result.

```
public String toString() {
    StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(" ");
    someListOfNumbers.forEach(l -> joiner.add(Long.toString(l)));
    return joiner.toString();
}
```

or use [`Collectors.joining()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-):

```
public String toString() {
    returns someListOfNumbers.stream()
        .map(String::valueOf)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
}
```

`StringBuilder` will be a more efficient when building the text but one can argue that above is more readable. Definitely one should avoid `+` operator when using `StringBuilder` and use methods like `append()` instead.

If you take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45165496/java-string-concatenation-and-interning) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54633351/is-string-concatenation-on-assignment-efficient/54633427#54633427) or other answers you will see that String concatenation is additionally optimized by the `javac` compiler e.g. if constants are concatenated with `+` operator then the compiler can insert the resulting constant into bytecode.

Comment: `joiner::add` won't work if `someListOfNumbers` is actually a list of numbers.

Comment: StringJoiner needs you to turn all the numbers into intermediate Strings first, whereas StringBuilder can directly output the numbers into its internal buffer, so I'd use StringBuilder (does not make the code shorter anyway).

Answer (score 3):

```
out.append( " " + item);
```

In above statement there seems a problem here `" " + item` as its combining string with a long. As string is immutable so `+` operator for string creates a new copy of String in memory. An optimal solution could be using

```
out.append(' ').append(item);
```

Or even

```
out.append(" ").append(item);
```

In the both above scenarios, as StringBuilder is Mutable so extra memory space is not require to save new concatinated string. Hence its more optimal.

Comment: Maybe also size the StringBuilder's capacity to some estimate upfront (`someListOfNumbers.size() * 4` or such) to avoid having it to resize repeatedly.

Comment: Right, But its only possible if we really now the exact length of characters in the resulting string, otherwise it could cause exception.

Comment: @AsadChoudhary no, it won't cause an exception, it will just resize.

Comment: i mean the index out of bound exception if characters length increases from the given size. Is it not?

Comment: @AsadChoudhary no, it will just resize.

Answer (score 1):

A modern way would leave the manipulation of the string builder to a library method:

```
public String toString() {
    return someListOfNumbers.stream()
            .map(Number::toString)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
}
```

I have assumed that `someListOfNumbers` is a `List<Long>`. My method doesn’t give the exact same result as yours: Your result has a leading space that I have left out. If you need that space, you may either prepend it yourself or use:

```
            .collect(Collectors.joining(" ", " ", ""));
```

The three-arg `joining` expects delimiter, prefix and suffix in the mentioned order (I am giving the empty string as suffix).

Side note: I had wanted to use `.map(Long::toString)`, but it doesn’t compile because it is ambiguous. Here `toString` may refer to either the no-arg `Long.toString` or to the static one-arg `Long.toString(long)`. I solved it referring to it via the superclass of `Long`: `Number::toString`. Another solution would be `.map(String::valueOf)` as in Karol Dowbecki’s answer.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get rid of a trailing or leading zero, you have to check the index of the item that is currently handled in the loop.

Here are three examples which build a `String` that does not have anything to trim afterwards:

```
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    // iterate in a classic for-loop checking for item at index 0
    for (int i = 0; i < someListOfNumbers.size(); i++) {
        long item = someListOfNumbers.get(i);
        if (i == 0) {
            // in this case, avoid a leading zero
            out.append(item);
        } else {
            out.append(" ").append(item);
        }
    }
    return out.toString();
}

public String toString() {
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    // iterate in a classic for-loop checking for item at last index
    for (int i = 0; i < someListOfNumbers.size(); i++) {
        long item = someListOfNumbers.get(i);
        if (i == someListOfNumbers.size() - 1) {
            out.append(item).append(" ");
        } else {
            // this case avoids a trailing zero
            out.append(item);
        }
    }
    return out.toString();
}

public String toString() {
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    // add the first element and iterate from 1 to end afterwards 
    // (this requires a check for an empty list)
    out.append(someListOfNumbers.get(0));
    for (int i = 1; i < someListOfNumbers.size(); i++) {
        out.append(" ").append(someListOfNumbers.get(i));
    }
    return out.toString();
}
```

You could even use you own method, but with an enhanced `for`-loop, you would have to use `indexOf` and then perform the check. I wouldn't want that, but it is your decision.

Comment: I prefer the third of the three examples. Having a special case inside a `for` loop is a bit, just a little bit of an antipattern, and in this case it is easily avoided.

Comment: @OleV.V.sure, antipatterns should be avoided in every case, no matter how *big* they are ;-) But in this case, it is about correctly working code, not code quality, I think.

Comment: I agree about antipatterns, and I may also have used a strong word here. I tend not to agree about what it’s about: to me it’s always also about code quality. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @OleV.V. I don't doubt it is always about code quality to you now, which is great. But hadn't there been a time when you did not know about code quality and just wanted to learn the basics? I can't really tell what OP wants, but it appears not to be mainly code quality but code that meets some functional requirements.

Comment: It could be a long and interesting discussion, but there isn’t room for it here. When I teach programming to beginners, I almost from day one tell them that programming is about writing code that “the next programmer” can read, understand and maintain.

Comment: @OleV.V that's definitely **the** right way to teach programming. Good for your students, I had several teachers who thought differently...