# why there is different output for below two codes?

Tags: java, string

The below program outputs false

```
    String s1="a";
    String s2="b";
    String s3=s1+s2;
    String s4="ab";

    if(s3==s4)
    {
        System.out.println("true");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("false");
    }
```

and this code outputs true

```
String s3="a"+"b";
  String s4="ab";

  if(s3==s4)
  {
      System.out.println("true");
  }
  else
  {
      System.out.println("false");
  }
```

Shouldn't the output in first case be true? As while creating String s4="ab" there is already an object with value "ab" in the string constant pool.

Comment: Why are people so obsessed with the string constant pool and how the compiler chooses to implement String concatenation? The only thing you need to know is to never compare Strings with `==`.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: @Thilo i was asked this question in an interview so i asked

Comment: @ Lutz the redirected question does not answer the actual question

Comment: If I was asked this in an interview my answer would be the same: "The only thing you need to know is to never compare Strings with `==`". If they are interviewing for business application developers and not compiler writers they are asking the wrong question.

Comment: @rajkumar.11 Maybe this one helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45165496/java-string-concatenation-and-interning

Answer (score 3):

In Java, you want to use `.equals()` instead of `==` to compare strings. Try the following.

```
String s1="a";
String s2="b";
String s3=s1+s2;
String s4="ab";

if(s3.equals(s4))
{
    System.out.println("true");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("false");
}
```

Comment: i am aware  of using  equals when we we want to compare the string values and == when we want to compare objects but my question is different.